# How can one count an amount of crossroads and junctions of a grid maze?

Tags: python, graph, maze

So recently I've started experimenting with python in terms of game dev and I now want to create a maze game. I've implemented 4 different algorithms (Prim's, Kruskal's, Recursive Backtracker, Hunt and Kill to be exact) to generate a maze. Each of them return a maze as a 2D python array. What I found ineresting is the amount of crucial desicions a player should/may take in order to solve a maze in a different generated mazes.

Meaning that whether a player faces a crossroad [image: crossroad - 3 decisions] or a junction[image: junction-2 decisions]

a player have to take a decision on their next step which might be crucial in terms of completion time and path lenght. This is severely simple to analyse by 'hand' when it comes to small mazes, but is there any possible code algorithm to count the amount of such crossroads and junctions in bigger mazes?

Answer (score 0):

For any given point, say `maze[x][y]`, you should be able to see if you're able to move to `maze[x-1][y]`, `maze[x+1][y]`, `maze[x][y-1]`, and `maze[x][y+1]`. If you can move to three, you have a junction. If you can get to all four, you have a crossroad.

Just be certain that you're doing a safety check on x and y equaling 0 or len - 1 so you don't get an exception on an overflow, or a loopback from 0 to -1.